# Ambiguous use of 'init' in Array mapped to String with chosen separators

Tags: arrays, swift, mapping

As @vadian suggested, I am learning Xcode from Paul Hudson's 100 days of SwiftUI to better understand the basics (even though I am still struggling with time to deliver working GitHub repository search - no it is not for the job I am working on right now).

I am doing a lesson on Arrays, so pretty basic stuff right now and I struggle to map the String from array on the sorted array. I don't get why, but I get the:

```
Ambiguous use of 'init'
```

error.

Here's the code:

```
let cities = ["London", "Tokyo", "Rome", "Budapest"]
print(cities.sorted())

let citiesSorted = cities.sorted()

let citiesSortedString = citiesSorted.map(String.init).joined(separator:", ")
```

And it's so really strange, since I pulled the similar thing out before in the same Playground but not with the sorted Array:

```
var schoolScoresString = schoolScores.map(String.init).joined(separator:", ")
print(schoolScoresString)
```

And yes I tried changing let to var. It didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cities` is already of type `[String]`, so you're passing a `String` to `String.init`, which obviously won't work. If you want to join an array of `String`s into a single `String`, remove the `map` and just call `joined` on the array.

```
let citiesSortedString = citiesSorted.joined(separator:", ")
```